# Detect when WiFi network fails to authenticate

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I am trying to connect to a WiFi network using `WiFiManager`. Here is the code I use to do so :

```
WifiManager manager = [...];
WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
manager.setWifiEnabled(true);

//Set SSID, PSK, etc...
[...]

//Connect to the network
int netId = manager.addNetwork(config);
if (netId == -1)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid PSK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}
manager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
manager.saveConfiguration();
```

Beforehand, I registered a `BroadcastReceiver` for the `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` action. I'm trying to detect when the connection succeeds or fails (for various reasons including authentication) by checking the `DetailedState` of the given `NetworkInfo`.

Everything works when the connection succeeds, but for some reason my receiver isn't "executed" when the connection fails. The network is added to the device's list, I can see it by going into WiFi Settings, but it does not try to connect (or it does try to connect but doesn't notify my receiver).

Any clue ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve what I wanted.

To detect that the connection succeeded, register the `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast intent and check for the `NetworkInfo.DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR` detailed state (for WiFi obviously).

To detect that the connection failed, register the `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast intent and check for any `WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR` integer extra (typically `WifiManager.ERROR_AUTHENTICATING`). You may need to gain access for Android  hidden API to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

The enableNetwork method return true if the connection status is success.
This works fine on success but is not the best method to check the failed status (return true if the connection failed after the first step authentication).

I think that you can check in the networkInfo object the actual connected network to see if the request is ok:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
```

Comment: I didn't know that the `enableNetwork` method returned that, I'm going to test it as soon as I can, thanks for the input ! But aren't WiFi connections asynchronous, hence the need for the `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` ? Or can I trust the `enableNetwork` return value ? I'm only interested in seeing if it failed (due tu authentication), I can see when it succeeded using the "obtaining ip address" event.

Comment: I've tried with a Galaxy Core and with a S4 the enableNetwork return and I have two different scenarios:
1. (Core) - If the authentication failed, return false and not save the used password in the WiFi settings;
2. (S4) - If the authentication failed, return true and save the password in the WiFi settings (I see a message like "there's an error on authentication").
I think that is better to see the status using the NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION if you don't want to have a lot of errors...

Comment: But I can't, and that's the point of this question : using `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` to see if the connection failed isn't working for me

Comment: Mh.. That's strange. Can you post here how you register it and how do you use it?

Comment: I register it using `registerReceiver` with the proper `IntentFilter`. I know it works because I can use it to see when the connection succeeded. Once in the `onReceive` method, I get the `NetworkInfo` : `NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);` and I check for the detailed state : `if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && info.getDetailedState() == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR) {...}`. I would like to do the same with `NetworkInfo.DetailedState.FAILED` bue the receiver is never fired with this info.

Comment: Try to log each `info.getDetailedState()` to check which are the checked states on all the failed connection process. I think that you can find a `NetworkInfo.DetailedState.DISCONNECTED` one. (here you can see the DetailedState online doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState.html).

Comment: IIRC it doesn't even try to connect when using a wrong key so it doesn't fire anything in the event, I might need to check again on that one